# Can macOS 10.14 (mojave) output a 4K HDR desktop to a 4K HDR TV?

Tags: macos, display, hdmi, 4k, hdr

How can I get macOS 10.14 on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) to output the macOS UI (desktop) in HDR mode to my Samsung Q6F 4K HDR TV display?

I'm using a USB-C/Thunderbolt to HDMI 2 dongle and an HDMI 2.0 certified cable. Also, the same Samsung Q6F 4K HDR TV when connected to a Windows 10 desktop seems to operate in HDR mode. i.e. Windows 10 switched to HDR mode and videos (youtube or separate video files) also appear in HDR. Am I missing a macOS setting? Do I need an update or a new dongle?

---

System info

```
Radeon Pro 455:

  Chipset Model:    AMD Radeon Pro 455
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 2 GB
  Vendor:   AMD (0x1002)
  Device ID:    0x67ef
  Revision ID:  0x00c7
  ROM Revision: 113-C980AF-908
  VBIOS Version:    113-C9801AP-028
  EFI Driver Version:   01.A0.908
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.29 [3.2.8]
  Metal:    Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily2 v1
  Displays:
SAMSUNG:
  Resolution:   3840 x 2160 (2160p 4K UHD - Ultra High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz
  Framebuffer Depth:    30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
  Connection Type:  DVI or HDMI
  Adapter Firmware Version: 7.26
  Television:   Yes
```